# I got a race condition for following snippet

Tags: java, multithreading

When the System.out.println inside the ThreadA is un-commented, it runs fine.

Is race condition is related with System.out.println

For flushing out to system console does it takes time and runs fine.

What could be solution for this question to run smoothly without interruption

```
package com.test.concurrency;
 class ThreadA extends Thread{
private int sum = 0;
@Override
public void run(){
    synchronized (this) {
                     //System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0; i<100 ;i++){
            sum += i;
        }
        notify();   
    }
}
public int getSum(){
    return sum;
}
  }

public class WaitNNotify {
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    ThreadA t= new ThreadA ();
    t.start();
    System.out.println("Waiting for ThreadA to complete..."+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    synchronized (t) {
        try{
            t.wait();

            System.out.println("Finally the Thread is notified ... "+t.getSum());       
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: where do you start `ThreadA`, also for thread completion waiting on `main` thread you should have used `join`

Comment: What result do you get when you run this code? What result do you *expect* to get?

Comment: @Harsh ThreadA is already started check in the above snippet.I just want the sum from the above thread, it hangs if i run the code

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder  I want to get the sum from above thread

Comment: This question is likely unanswerable until you provide a full working example, and not just snippets.

Comment: ThreadA t= new ThreadA ();
    t.setName("Thread Main");
    t.start();
    System.out.println("Waiting for ThreadA to complete..."+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    synchronized (t) {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);;
  System.out.println("Finally the Thread is notified ... "+t.getSum());
    }

Comment: When I un comment the Sysout in the ThreadA, it normally runs fine.Two threads (Main and ThreadA) ,ThreadA starts first it tries to notify and nobody is waiting on object and hangs indefinitely I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `join` and not `wait-notify` for your scenario, Below is sample implemenation:

```
class ThreadA extends Thread {
    private int sum = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
            System.out.println();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                sum += i;
            }
    }
    public int getSum() {
        return sum;
    }
}

public class WaitNNotify {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadA t = new ThreadA();
        t.start();
        System.out.println("Waiting for ThreadA to complete..."+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            t.join();
            System.out.println("Finally the Thread is completed ... "+ t.getSum());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question is not to get the sum. I have problems with indefinite wait,when I un comment the sysout in Thread it works fine. Can you explain why it is ?

Comment: I don't know how your program will run on uncommenting `sysout`, for all practical reasons it will not since `t.wait` is called before `t.start` so `t.start` is never called as `wait` never exit without `notify`. Only change you can do is first starting thread then calling  `wait`. Hope this help..

Comment: Yes the above is modified its not wait and start, So I started and gone for wait even the same indefinite wait happens, When I uncomment sysout it runs fine Why what could be reason

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `synchronized` block and the `notify()` method call from `ThreadA`, and replace `wait()` with `join()`:

```
public void run(){
        //System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0; i<100 ;i++){
            sum += i;
        } 
}
```

and

```
t.join();
```